# display image on second page from dropdown from first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <script>
function fctCheck(gender) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByName("subselector");
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(gender).style.display = "block";
}


$('#men').on('change', function() {
  $("#mtsm").css('display', (this.value == 'tsm') ? 'block' : 'none');
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore.active').each(function() {
    $('.container ').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image") + ')');
  });
  $('.colore').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').css('src', '');
    $('.container ').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image") + ')');
    $('.container7').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image-back") + ')');
  });
  $('#toggler').click(function() {
    var tmp = $('.container').css('background-image');
    $('.container').css('background-image', $('.container7').css('background-image'));

    $('.container7').css('background-image', tmp);
  });
});
</script>
```

I have a code that allows users to pick a shirt color and style this is all in the first page. What I want is lets say the user picks a red short sleeve shirt from a drop down menu I want to be able to display an image of the red shirt on the second page. How can I do this without having to go through a lot of code changing?

```html
<select id="Gender" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
        <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
        <option value="men">Men</option>
        <option value="wemen">Wemen</option>
        <option value="girls">Girls</option>
        <option value="boys">boys</option>
    </select>  
    <br>
       <br>
    <select id="men" name="subselector" style="display:none">
      <option value="">Choose an item</option> 
      <option value="tsm">T-Shirt</option>
      <option value="lsm">long sleeve</option>
     <option value="tankm">Tank Top</option>
     <option value="fzhm">Full zip Hood</option>
     <option value="pohm">Pull over Hood</option>
     <option value="fzfm">Full zip Fleece</option>
     <option value="fm">Fleece</option>
    </select>  
    
    <select id= value="slw">short sleeve</option>
 
    </select>  
    
     <select id="girls" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="shortsg">shorts</option>
        
    </select>  
 <select id="boys" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="tshirtb">tshirt</option>
    </select>  
     <div style='display:none;' id="wsl">
                       <div class="colore white" data-image="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi.png">
                </div>
                <div class="colore black" data-image="http://mebe.co/ford">
                </div>
                <div class="colore yellow" data-image="http://mebe.co/f150">
                </div>
                <div class="colore orange" data-image="http://mebe.co/yukon">
                </div>
                <div class="colore red" data-image="http://mebe.co/370z">
                </div>
            </div>
            
              <div style='display:none;' id="mtsm">
    <div class="colore white active" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/white.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/whiteback.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore black" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/black.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/whiteback.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore yellow" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/yellow.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/orange.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore orange" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/orange.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/yellow.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore red" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/red.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/black.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please include the js code as well

Comment: that is the js for my image to display on my first page (front image shirt) i want to display the same color shirt but back part of it on the second page

Comment: if you dont want to go through alot of code, suggested using ajax.

Comment: i was thinking javascript but i dont know where to start

Comment: pick the color code on dropdown change and store it on the local storage(HTML5). Then on your second page access your Local storage. Start coding. If you are stuck show us your code.

Comment: @Mir can you give me an example please

Comment: There is no direct example but searching for the terms on google may help.

Comment: @loosemymind do still need advice on that?